# Draw the graph of the function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the question
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSqiz.jpg)

I did the graph and found the Y value, (not sure I have done it right though, please correct if I have done it wrong)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd3Rs.jpg)

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftu60.jpg)

For question

i) For the first question I got -6
[Question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP7pB.jpg)

ii) Not sure how to find the roots of f(x) = 0
how would I do that?

iii) The range of values of x for which f(x) is increasing.
Can you please explain, how would you approach this.

Thank you

Edit:
Corrected graph:

[Corrected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rANq.jpg)

Question 1,2,3 thanks to @Eric Towers and @Bright Star feedback

[Q1,2,3 Answered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLklD.jpg) *Update 1 - Incorrect

[Q1,2,3 Answered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqKXz.jpg)
*Update 2 - Incomplete answer

[Q1,2,3 Answered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTumL.jpg)
*Update 3 - Corrected

Comment: ii) is asking you for which values of $x$ do we have $f(x)=0$, which you have already worked out.

Comment: @Loobear23 Are you saying my table is the answer for question 2 ?

Comment: I’m saying that you have calculated $f(x)$ (which is the same thing as $y$) for integers $x$ between $-4$ and $3$. The question is asking which values $x$ do we have $y=0$. Your table shows there are two of them

Comment: @Loobear23 : Roots are $x$-values, not points on the graph.  The roots of $(x-1)(x-2)$ are $1$ and $2$.  Your solution would benefit from clear sentences telling the reader what you are doing.  For instance, you have replicated your table, but do not tell the reader why a list of coordinate pairs is appearing.  Your list of coordinate pairs is sufficient to answer the question about roots, so it is unclear why you *also* factor $f$ -- some words of explanation are in order.  After a complicated calculation, like your part ii, it is a good idea to tell your reader what the result is.  In words.

Comment: @EricTowers I have updated the answer, can you please check and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: In part i: your first line is a sentence.  Put a period at the end and that's all you need.  Read your part ii out loud : are these the words you would say to another human being to communicate your answer?  Further, you have not answered part ii -- there are certainly a lot of points on the graph here, but where is the list of two roots?  For part iii: while the graph of f is horizontal at $-1/2$, that's not how increasing is defined; $f(-1/2) < f(x)$ for all $x$ satisfying $-1/2 < x$ (and also $-4 \leq x \leq 3$), so you should include $-1/2$ in your interval.

Comment: @EricTowers for part 3, besides f(−1/2)<f(x) for all x satisfying −1/2<x (and also −4≤x≤3), I could also say as the Answer to be  -0.5 ≤ x ≤ 3, correct ?

Comment: Yes.  You might notice that my Answer gives a closed interval for part iii...

Comment: @EricTowers And for part two, just giving the two roots of (-3,0), (2, 0) would be enough ? I mean without factorizing and showing how I got those numbers as proof, besides looking at the graph.

Comment: What words would you say to a human being standing next to you to convince them you had found two roots, what those roots are, and that there were no more roots in the interval $[-4,3]$?  Again, roots are $x$-values, not points on a graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122752/discussion-between-mike-salaru-and-eric-towers).

Comment: @EricTowers 
The two roots found are (-3,0), (2,0). The reason those are the only two roots in the interval of [-4,-3], is because that's where the function f(x) crosses the x-axis.
Does that sound ok ?

Comment: Again, again: roots are x-values, not points on a graph.  The roots you have found are x = -3 and x = 2.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has a typo' on the row for $x = 3$.  The second column should have "$3^2 + 3 - 6$", giving $f(3) = 6$.  It was odd that your graph of a parabola wasn't symmetric, so I checked your table.

i):  Yes.  $(-1)^2 - 1 - 6 = -6$.

ii):  You introduced "$y$" in your work.  You were given "$f(x)$".  In your table, your "$y$" column is your collection of values of $f(x)$.  Your table has two values of $x$ for which $y(x) = 0$, so you have found both roots.

iii): Look at your graph, reading from left-to-right.  As we start, it decreases -- that is, the height of the points on the graph is decreasing, meaning that as $x$ increases, $f(x)$ decreases.  Then we reach a minimum at a point whose $x$-coordinate is between $-1$ and $0$ and whose $y$-coordinate is between $-6$ and $-7$.  Afterwards, it increases.  Excepting your incorrect value for $f(3)$, you should see that your graph is symmetric.  From that symmetry, you should know the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola (the point of the graph where $f(x)$ is minimized).  Clearly, the function is increasing everywhere to the right of that (restricted to the interval which you have graphed), so for $x$s in an interval of the form $[a, 3]$, $f$ is increasing.  (... and $a$ is the $x$-coordinate of the minimum.)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question, with the corrections. Please let me know if any further changes are needed.